# How to fix the "Could not find file 'C:\CoolApp.vshost.exe.config' exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

I have a program that's navigating to different websites using a Browser Winforms control, on it's own, but after 5-10 seconds it throws the above exception in Visual Studio and highlighting this line:

```
Application.Run (new MainForm ());
```

in `Program.cs`.

Also I can see the exception location, because I turned on the CLR exceptions option.

But why is this happening. I am not doing anything with the vshost. How can I fix this?

EDIT: Call stack:

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int errorCode, string maybeFullPath) + 0x4b7 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.IO.FileStream.Init(string path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access = Read, int rights, bool useRights = false, System.IO.FileShare share, int bufferSize = 4096, System.IO.FileOptions options, Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, string msgPath = "CoolApp.vshost.exe.config", bool bFromProxy) + 0xa14 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(string path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, int bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options, string msgPath, bool bFromProxy) + 0x8a bytes 
    mscorlib.dll!System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(string path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access) + 0x54 bytes    
    System.dll!System.Uri.ParseConfigFile(string file, out System.Uri.IdnScopeFromConfig idnStateConfig, out System.Uri.IriParsingFromConfig iriParsingConfig) Line 1106    C#
    System.dll!System.Uri.GetConfig(ref System.UriIdnScope idnScope = None, ref bool iriParsing = false) Line 1009  C#
    System.dll!System.Uri.InitializeUriConfig() Line 907 + 0x13 bytes   C#
    System.dll!System.Uri.InitializeUri(System.Uri.ParsingError err = None, System.UriKind uriKind, out System.UriFormatException e = null) Line 108 + 0x5 bytes    C#
    System.dll!System.Uri.CreateThis(string uri, bool dontEscape, System.UriKind uriKind) Line 50   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.WebBrowserEvent.BeforeNavigate2(object pDisp, ref object urlObject, ref object flags, ref object targetFrameName, ref object postData, ref object headers, ref bool cancel = false) Line 1934 + 0x1a bytes C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(int dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) Line 2106 + 0xc bytes  C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason = -1, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context = {System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext}) Line 3377 + 0x35 bytes    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Line 3261 + 0xd bytes   C#
>   CoolApp.exe!CoolApp.Program.Main() Line 18 + 0x28 bytes C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x47 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x9b bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x4d bytes
```

Comment: @Hans: I added the call stack, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Is `C:\CoolApp` your exe folder and do you have a *.config file there? Are you copying/moving the .EXE or changing current folder?

Comment: @Hans: Thanks, I shortened path but it's inside my original projects bin/debug or release folder. I don't see a config file there, only exe, dll, pdb, vshost.exe and vshost.exe.manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

You can find details about VSHost from here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtemp/archive/2004/08/17/215764.aspx

Also I found a similar question in SO : [mysterious exception "Could not find file 'D:\xxxx\bin\Debug\xxx.vshost.exe.config'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271698/wpf-mysterious-exception-could-not-find-file-d-xxxx-bin-debug-xxx-vshost-exe)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to run the program compiled in debug mode on machine that have no debugger installed.

Comment: Thanks, but I was compiling the release version. Debugger is installed though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the problem, try to check the box "Enable Just My Code (Managed only)" in Tools/Options/Debugging/General